# Is there a way to make TFS code search recognize the "@" symbol?

Tags: tfs, escaping, azure-devops, code-search

I am searching for all occurrences of an out of date email domain in my codebase on TFS. Specifically, I am searching for "@testexample.com". However, the search seems to completely ignore the "@" symbol.

If I search "@testexample.com", I get all occurrences of "testexample.com". I have also tried "*@testexample.com" but prefix wildcards aren't allowed in code search.

Comment: Vote on my feature request here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/893393/allow-non-alphanumeric-characters-in-code-search.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's not supported.

Checked for some characters in code search. You can't use the symbol characters except `*` and `?` as part of your search query, which including below characters: . , : ; / \ ` ' " @ = ! # $ & + ^ | ~ < > ( ) { } [ ]. The search will simply ignore these symbols.

But you can use wildcard characters * and ? to broaden your search.

> You can use wildcard characters anywhere in your search string except
>   as a prefix in a simple search string or a query that uses a code type
>   filter. For example, you cannot use a search query such as
>   ***RequestHandler** or **class:?RequestHandler**. However, you can use prefix wildcards with the other search filter functions; for example, the
>   search query strings **file:*RequestHandler.cs** and **repo:?Handlers** are
>   valid.

Please see [Broaden your search with wildcards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/search/code/advanced-search#broaden-your-search-with-wildcards) for details.

If you want to search the strings including these symbol exactly(such as '@' here), you can code search with other strings (eg, `testexample.com` here) to narrow down the scope first, then copy the specific code to text editor which support the symbols (eg, Notepad++), then search stings with the symbol characters.

Besides, if you are using Git, another workaround is using the code search tool [Hound: a lightning fast code search tool](https://github.com/etsy/Hound), it supports the symbol characters. Reference this thread to use it: [How can I publish source code (Visual Studio) on a intranet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46283650/how-can-i-publish-source-code-visual-studio-on-a-intranet)

Comment: I can indeed confirm that searching on special characters like "[" for instance, does not work on an on premise Tfs2018 instance. 
I am however intrigued why searching on the exact same string works on VSTS? I would have expected it to work, seeing that the 
official Microsoft documentation states that it should work for these versions (VSTS | TFS 2018 | TFS 2017)
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/project/search/advanced-code-search-syntax?view=vsts