# Search for XML Nodes in Azure DevOps Server Code Search

Tags: azure-devops

We have recently configured our ADS 2020.1 with ElasticSearch, which will now allow us to do Code searches.

I checked the [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/project/search/functional-code-search?view=azure-devops), but are unable to find an answer to my current "issue".

Suppose i want to find all files where we have the this code

```
<Project>
```

When i search it just as `<Project>` i get many hits for "Project" in the code.
When i search for `"<Project>"` i get the same result as above.
Also tried `\<Project\>` or `"\<Project\>"`

How can i properly search for the <> brackets in the code?

I have the same questions for searches including the = sign or anything like that, i cannot find the way to include this and search as text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After further search i found another topic here

[Is there a way to make TFS code search recognize the "@" symbol?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46411923/is-there-a-way-to-make-tfs-code-search-recognize-the-symbol/46417298#46417298)

```
That's not supported.

Checked for some characters in code search. You can't use the symbol characters except * and ? as part of your search query, which including below characters: . , : ; / \ ` ' " @ = ! # $ & + ^ | ~ < > ( ) { } [ ]. The search will simply ignore these symbols.
```

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/allow-non-alphanumeric-characters-in-code-search/893393