# TFS code search find <Button>

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I want to find all usages of my react component in code.
I tried `<Button>`  but Special chars `<>` are not supported.
Tried `"Button"` and i get `"Button"` and `button` with lowercase as results as well.
So exact match is also not supported.

Is there is a way to find a string exactly without any additional results?

Comment: Vote on my feature request here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/893393/allow-non-alphanumeric-characters-in-code-search.html

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, search symbols (`<>` and `""` in your scenario) is not supported in code search.

In tfs the symbol `""` is used for finding an exact match to **a set of words** by enclosing your search terms in double-quotes. For example, "Client not found".

> Is there is a way to find a string exactly without any additional
>   results?

Yes, but it seems a little complex, just reference my answer in another thread:[Is there a way to make TFS code search recognize the "@" symbol?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46411923/is-there-a-way-to-make-tfs-code-search-recognize-the-symbol)

> Checked for some characters in code search. You can't use the symbol
>   characters except `*` and `?` as part of your search query, which
>   including below characters: . , : ; / \ ` ' " @ = ! # $ & + ^ | ~ < >
>   ( ) { } [ ]. The search will simply ignore these symbols.
>
> But you can use wildcard characters * and ? to broaden your search.
>
> > You can use wildcard characters anywhere in your search string except
> >     as a prefix in a simple search string or a query that uses a code type
> >     filter. For example, you cannot use a search query such as
> >     ***RequestHandler** or **class:?RequestHandler**. However, you can use prefix wildcards with the other search filter functions; for
> >     example, the
> >     search query strings **file:*RequestHandler.cs** and **repo:?Handlers** are
> >     valid.
>
> Please see [Broaden your search with wildcards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/search/code/advanced-search#broaden-your-search-with-wildcards) for details.
>
> If you want to search the strings including these symbol exactly(such
>   as '@' here), you can code search with other strings (eg,
>   `testexample.com` here) to narrow down the scope first, then copy the
>   specific code to text editor which support the symbols (eg,
>   Notepad++), then search stings with the symbol characters.
>
> Besides, if you are using Git, another workaround is using the code
>   search tool [Hound: a lightning fast code search tool](https://github.com/etsy/Hound), it supports
>   the symbol characters. Reference this thread to use it:
>   [How can I publish source code (Visual Studio) on a intranet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46283650/how-can-i-publish-source-code-visual-studio-on-a-intranet)

Also, there is a [**User Voice here**](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/31744555-search-in-code-should-support-exact-literal-text-s) to suggest the feature, you can go and vote it up to achieve that in future.

Comment: @AlexanderGorelik Is the answer helpful for you? any update?

Comment: Here in 2023, I can respond to this: The answer is accurate, but the feature is less than worthless. The only way to search code in Azure Devops is to download all of your repos and do it yourself.